# Dynamic SQL in column name to get max of that column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have the below query and I want to get the max of column that create in Dynamic SQL. But the results are not identical.
Can you please help me on this?

```
DECLARE @RT VARCHAR(6)
SET @RT     = 'RT1401'

SELECT      max(KWh_RT1401A_BLU)    AS Test1,
            max('KWh_'+@RT+'A_BLU') AS Test2

            FROM [PlantData].[dbo].[POD14_Kwh]
            where timestamp >='2017-08-24'
```

and the result is:

```
Test1         Test2
------------- ---------------
730.3399      KWh_RT1401A_BLU
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll need dyanmic sql for this like below

```
DECLARE @RT VARCHAR(6)
SET @RT     = 'RT1401'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL=' SELECT max(KWh_RT1401A_BLU) AS Test1, '+
         ' max(KWh_'+@RT+'A_BLU) AS Test2 '+
         ' FROM [PlantData].[dbo].[POD14_Kwh] '+
         ' where timestamp >=''2017-08-24'''
EXEC( @SQL)
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/VVWOM31665)**</kbd>

**based on your comment**

> Now, I have bigger problem, I can't pass datetime into my dynamic SQL. I also try Cast / Convert, in triple quote but still has issue

modified solution is below

```
CREATE TABLE [POD14_Kwh]( [KWh_RT1401A_BLU] int, timestamp datetime)
INSERT INTO POD14_Kwh VALUES
(730.3399,'2017-08-24 00:00:00'),(1.00,'2017-08-24 00:00:00');

DECLARE @RT VARCHAR(6)
SET @RT     = 'RT1401'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
SET @dt = '2017-08-24 00:00:00'



SET @SQL=' SELECT max(KWh_RT1401A_BLU) AS Test1, '+
         ' max(KWh_'+@RT+'A_BLU) AS Test2 '+
         ' FROM [POD14_Kwh] '+
         ' where timestamp >='''+CAST(@dt as varchar(max))+''''
EXEC( @SQL)
```

**[demo link](http://rextester.com/QSFZ57842)**

Comment: Thank you very much @DhruvJoshi

Comment: @Farhad Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered

Comment: Now, I have bigger problem, 
I can't pass datetime into my dynamic SQL.
I also try Cast / Convert, in triple quote but still has issue.

Answer (score 2):

`Dhruv Joshi` is correct you'll need to use dynamic SQL. In your example you had created a string rather than referenced a column name. Be sure the Execute the dynamic SQL string to receive the desired output too.

```
DECLARE @RT VARCHAR(6)
        ,@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @RT     = 'RT1401'


SET @SQL=' SELECT max(KWh_RT1401A_BLU) AS Test1, '+
         ' max(KWh_'+@RT+'A_BLU) AS Test2 '+
         ' FROM [PlantData].[dbo].[POD14_Kwh] '+
         ' where timestamp >= ''2017-08-24'''

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: what's the differance between your ans and Dhruv joshi ans

Comment: This wouldn't work - you need to have the exec @sql inside brackets

Comment: I wanted to explain why the example in the question wouldn't work, also there was to many comma's to the left of the date which broke the string - Unfortunately I'm unable to edit others answers or questions.